# Perform lookup for arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to perform aggregation for the following:

MONTHLY_COLLECTION

```
{
"month_year" : "01-2020",
"dates" : {
    "1": [ new ObjectId("1"), new ObjectId("2") ], // array of Booking Collection IDS
    "5": [ new ObjectId("3")],
    ...
},
```

BOOKING_COLLECTION

```
{
  "_id": 1 ,
  ... 
},

{
  "_id": 57 ,
  ... 
},

{
  "_id": 2 ,
  ... 
},
{
  "_id": 3 ,
  ... 
},

...
```

desired output:

```
{
  "_id": 1 ,
  ... 
},

{
  "_id": 2 ,
  ... 
},

{
  "_id": 3 ,
  ... 
},
```

such that I get only the booking documents which fall within the given `month_years.dates`

```
db.collection(MONTHLY_COLLECTION).aggregate([
        {
            "$match": { month_year: { "$in": [`01-2023`, `08-2023`] } },
        },
       ???
    ])
```

so how do I iterate over the keys in an object and then iterate over their individual arrays via $lookup?

Comment: You may want to review and change your data model.  In general, using _**any**_ data as field names is a MongoDB anti-pattern.  In addition, it's usually best to use BSON dates for dates, or at least ISO8601 formatted strings - it makes comparisons, etc., much easier.